# Custom UL styles in tinymce editor

Tags: wordpress, tinymce, visual-editor

I want to change the structure of UL list in tinyMCE editor from:

```
<ul>
   <li>item 1</li>
   <li>item 2</li>
</ul>
```

to:

```
<ul>
   <li><i class="icon"></i> item 1</li>
   <li><i class="icon"></i> item 2</li>
</ul>
```

I'm using Wordpress and want to know if this can be done using style formats -> http://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE_Custom_Styles

I have tried:

```
function custom_mce_before_init_insert_formats($init_array) {
    $style_formats = array(
        array(
            'title' => 'arrow',
            'inline' => 'i',
            'classes' => 'icon',
            'wrapper' => false
        )
    );  
    $init_array['style_formats'] = json_encode($style_formats);

    return $init_array;  
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'custom_mce_before_init_insert_formats');
```

but this will generate not propriate code:

```
<ul>
   <li><i class="icon">item 1</i></li>
   <li><i class="icon">item 2</i></li>
</ul>
```

Any solution will be very helpfull.

Thank you.

Comment: Have tried something – if so, add it to your question, please.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your [valid_elements](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/configuration%3avalid_elements) setting to make sure tinymce accepts empty i-tags?
If there is something like `-i` in the config i-tags will get stripped out.

Comment: I'm not sure if I found right config but there is only `*[*]` as valid elements. I'm usign Wordpress 3.5.1 - where the config file is located?

Comment: i don't know where, but there was a tinymce bug in one or several version that didn't recognize *[*]